# What is the memory order of JUCE's atomic facilities?

Tags: c++, atomic, juce

In boost library and C++11 standard library, the atomic operations have *memory order* modifiers which limit the instruction reorder. However, JUCE's atomic facilities don't have this. So does JUCE atomic use the most stringent *memory order* assertion, so that I don't need to concern that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source file at https://github.com/julianstorer/JUCE/blob/master/modules/juce_core/memory/juce_Atomic.h, the implementation of Atomic class in JUCE uses compiler intrinsics or platform-specific calls that are equivalent to atomic operations with `memory_order_seq_cst` ordering in C++11.